# SpecFlow only calls first line of scenario

Tags: c#, nunit, bdd, specflow

I'm using a `SpecFlow` scenario for logging my users in.

I've got two indentical lines seperated by an `And`, but the binding get's only called for the first line. I'm using the following code:

**Background:**

```
Given User 'User1' at 'RC1' logged in
And User 'User2' at 'RC2' logged in
```

**Binding:**

```
[Given(@"User '(.*)' at '(.*)' logged in")]
public void GivenUserAtLoggedIn(string p0, string p1)
{
    new Login(p1, p0);
    ScenarioContext.Current.Pending();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove the line

```
ScenarioContext.Current.Pending();
```

As that stops the execution of the full scenario.